# Slicing with sed

Tags: bash, shell, command, slice

I have a file named servers.txt which contains

```
Mysqlserver=172.15.23.23
```

How can I slice out the IP after the '='?

This didn't work:

```
cat servers.txt | sed =*
```

Comment: Just `cut -d= -f2 file` can do the job

Comment: What does -d means ? as I have understood it correct -f2 means after '=' and if I change it to -f1 will show the data before

Comment: `man cut` will tell you all you want to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
cat servers.txt|sed 's/^.*=//g'
```

Comment: or `sed 's/.*=//' servers.txt`